# What is the shape/best fit equation for this curve in this image?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, curves, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In my personal research project, I've generated the below graph using the following equation:

$$D(z)=\frac{1}{2^z}-2\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2^{z+1}}\bigg\rfloor$$

Where $z=a+bi$, with the hue of the graph corresponding to the value of $b$ and the brightness corresponding to the value of $a$.

This equation uses the following extension of the floor function to the complex numbers as:

$$\lfloor a+bi\rfloor=\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor i$$

I've rotated the original image 90 degrees clockwise to highlight the curve in question in a better orientation.

I've been able to deduce with reasonable certainty that the graph has main features that have a period of $\frac{\pi}{\ln(2)}$. I'm curious to what equation would best fit the largest black curve within the red lines. My first guess failed as it would seem that neither the shape of $\sec$ nor $\sec^2$ (scaled accordingly) fits. I apologize for my lack of proper preparation as I have not double checked if the horizontal axis in the image is at the correct altitude. I'm not a professionally trained mathematician in any regard.

[image: Graph]

I'm grateful for any suggestion or insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your discontinuities in intensity occur when the real part of

$$\frac1{2^{z+1}}$$ crosses an integer, i.e.

$$e^{-z\log2}=\frac{\cos(y\log 2)}{2^x}=2n$$

[image]

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for! What graphing software did you use?

Comment: @Graviton Microsoft Equation